# When do there exist $ n $ commuting, derivations which locally generate $ T_{A/k} $ as an $ A $-module?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, lie-algebras

Let $ \operatorname{Spec}(A) $ be a non-singular, $ n $-dimensional, affine variety over a field $ k $ of arbitrary characteristic.  For the definition of "variety" I use Hartshorne's definition, i.e., an integral, separated scheme, of finite type over an algebraically closed field $ k $.  Elements of $ T_{A/k} $ correspond to $ A $ derivations of $ A $ over $ k $ (here $ T_{A,k} \cong \operatorname{Hom}_{A}(\Omega_{A/k},A) $).  Because $ \operatorname{Spec}(A) $ is non-singular, $ T_{A/k} $ is a free $ A $ module of rank $ n $.  Therefore, derivations $ \delta_{1},\dots, \delta_{n} $ which generate $ A $ as an $ A $-module.

My questions are the following:

Question 1:  When does there exist a neighborhood $ D(h) \subseteq \operatorname{Spec}(A) $ such that on $ D(h) $ there are $ n $, commuting, derivations $ \delta_{1},\dots,\delta_{n} $ which generate $ T_{A_{h}/k} $ as an $ A_{h} $-module?

Question 2:  If $ \delta_{1},\delta_{2} $ are two commuting derivations, then when does there exist a neighborhood $ D(h) \subseteq \operatorname{Spec}(A) $ such that there exist $ \delta_{3},\dots,\delta_{n} \in T_{A_{h}/k} $ with the property that $ \delta_{1},\dots,\delta_{n} $ all commute?

Question 3:  If in addition the characteristic of the field $ k $ is zero, then can one answer question 1?

Question 4:  If in addition the characteristic of the field $ k $ is zero, then can one answer question 2?

Note that I am **not** requiring that any of $ \delta_{1},\dots,\delta_{n} $ be locally nilpotent as this imposes very strict rationality requirements on the variety $ \operatorname{Spec}(A) $.  I only desire them to commute.

Comment: I'm confused. Shouldn't derivations correspond to vector fields, not co-vector fields?

Comment: I am sorry @DavidESpeyer.  You are correct.

Comment: I have changed the question appropriately.

Comment: Okay, no problem. Good question!

Answer (score 3):

I believe I found the answer to these questions.  I will answer Question 2 as it is the most general.

Since $ A $ is a finitely generated $ k $-algebra, there is a surjection $ \phi^{\sharp}: k[x_{1},\dots,x_{N}] \to A $.  If $ \delta_{1},\delta_{2} \in T_{A/k} $, then there are commuting derivations $ \gamma_{i} $ equal to $ \phi_{\ast}(\delta_{i}) $.  The derivations $ \gamma_{i} $ are equal to $ \sum_{j=1}^{N} f^{(i)}_{j}(X) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{j}} $.  If $ H(X) $ is equal to
\begin{equation*}
\det\left(
\begin{matrix}
f^{(1)}_{1}(X) & f^{(1)}_{2}(X) \\
f^{(2)}_{1}(X) & f^{(2)}_{2}(X) 
\end{matrix}
\right)
\end{equation*}
then on $ D(H(X)) $ the matrix $ C(X) $ described below:
\begin{equation*}
C_{i,j}(X)=
\begin{cases}
 f^{(i)}_{j}(X) & \quad i \in \{1,2\} \\
0 & \quad i>2, \, j \in \{1,2\} \\
\delta(i,j) & \quad \text{o.w.}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
is invertible on $ D(H(X)) $ (here $ \delta(i,j) $ is the Kronecker delta).  Because
\begin{equation*}
\left(
\begin{matrix}
\gamma_{1} \\
\gamma_{2} \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{3}} \\
\vdots \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{N}}
\end{matrix}
\right) = C \left(
\begin{matrix}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{1}} \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{2}} \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{3}} \\
\vdots \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{N}}
\end{matrix}
\right)
\end{equation*}
the derivations $ \{\gamma_{1},\gamma_{2},\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{3}},\dots,\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{N}}\} $ commute and generate $ T_{k[X]/k} $ on $ D(H(X)) $.  The derivations $ \gamma_{1} $ and $ \gamma_{2} $ are clearly in $ \phi_{\ast}(T_{A/k}) $.

Denote $ I_{A/k[X]} $ by $ I $ and let $ \psi: T_{A/k} \to \operatorname{Hom}_{A}(I/I^{2},A) $ be the natural map obtained from standard exact sequence of differential modules by dualizing.  Because $ \gamma_{1},\gamma_{2} \in \phi_{\ast}(T_{A/k}) $,
\begin{align*}
0 &= \psi(\gamma_{1}) \\
&= \psi(\gamma_{2}).
\end{align*}
The $ k $-span of the derivations $ \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{3}},\dots,\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{N}} $ forms a vector space $ \mathbf{V} $.  If the dimension (as a vector space) of $ \psi(\mathbf{V}) $ is greater than $ N-n $, then
\begin{align*}
N-n &=\operatorname{rank}(\operatorname{Hom}_{A}(I/I^{2},A)) \\
&= \operatorname{rank}_{A}(A \otimes_{k} \mathbf{V}) \\
& >N-n.
\end{align*}
This is a contradiction, so there are $ n-2 $ derivations in $ \mathbf{V} $ (whose dimension is $ N-2 $) which are contained in the kernel of $ \psi $.  Call these derivations $ \gamma_{3},\dots,\gamma_{n} $.  Because $ \ker(\psi) = \operatorname{im}(\phi_{\ast}) $, there are derivations $ \delta_{3},\dots,\delta_{n} $ such that $ \phi_{\ast}(\delta_{i}) = \gamma_{i} $ for $ 1 \le i \le n $.

The morphism $ \phi_{\ast} $ is an injective, morphism of Lie Algebras from $ T_{A/k} $ to $ T_{k[X]/k} $.  So for $ 1 \le i,j \le n $,
\begin{align*}
0 &=[\gamma_{i},\gamma_{j}] \\
&= [\phi_{\ast}(\delta_{i}),\phi_{\ast}(\delta_{j})] \\
&= \phi_{\ast}([\delta_{i},\delta_{j}]).
\end{align*}
Since $ \phi_{\ast} $ is injective, $ [\delta_{i},\delta_{j}] $ is equal to zero for $ 1 \le i, j \le n $.  This should show that the answer to Questions 1-4 is that it should always be possible to find such derivations.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that such a neighborhood always exists in Question 1, at least over an algebraically closed ground field.

Let $p$ be the point of $\text{Spec}(A)$ around which you want to find such a neighborhood. Let $x_1$, $x_2$, ..., $x_n$ generate the maximal ideal at $p$. Then $dx_1$, $dx_2$, ..., $dx_n$ locally generated $\Omega^1_{A/k}$ as an $A$-module; passing to an open neighborhood of $p$, we can assume that $\Omega^1_{A/k} = A dx_1 \oplus A dx_2 \oplus \cdots \oplus A dx_n$.

Let $\pi_j : \Omega^1_{A/k} \to A$ extract the coefficient of $d x_j$ in this direct sum decomposition. Then $\pi_j \circ d$ is the derivation usually called $\tfrac{\partial}{\partial x_j}$. The derivations $\tfrac{\partial}{\partial x_1}$, $\tfrac{\partial}{\partial x_2}$, ..., $\tfrac{\partial}{\partial x_n}$ commute as you would expect; you can check this by working in the completion of $A$ at $p$, which is just $k[[x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n]]$.